# How to implement Harmony VRF?

Tags: harmony

First post. I am wondering how can I implement VRF into my code below. I am not too sureIF I can do IT I added the function but I dont know how to tie in the randomness to the info I provided.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";


contract Halos {
    enum Zodiac {Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, VIrgo,Libra, Scorpio, Sagittarius, CapriCorn, Aquarius, Pisces} 
    enum Abilities {Sword, Axe, Wand, Gun, Hammer, Fist}

    struct Halo {string name;
                      bool isCharacter;
                      uint dna;
                      Zodiac[] power; 
                      Abilities[] ability;                  
        }

    mapping(address => Halo) public halos;
    address[] public characters;

    modifier onlyIfRegistered() {
        require(halos[msg.sender].isCharacter);
        _;
    }

    function register() public returns(bool success) {
        require(!halos[msg.sender].isCharacter);
        characters.push(msg.sender);
        halos[msg.sender].isCharacter = true;
        return true;
    }

    function addPower(Zodiac a) public onlyIfRegistered returns(bool success) {
        halos[msg.sender].power.push(a);
        return true;
    }

    function getPower(address player, uint row) public view returns(Zodiac power) {
        return halos[player].power[row];
    }

    function vrf() public view returns (bytes32 result) {
        uint[1] memory bn;
        bn[0] = block.number;
        assembly {
          let memPtr := mload(0x40)
          if iszero(staticcall(not(0), 0xff, bn, 0x20, memPtr, 0x20)) {
            invalid()
          }
          result := mload(memPtr)
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: The same function is implemented here as `generateRand()`, although `block.number` is not used or `bn[0]`. They are predictable! 

https://github.com/harmony-one/harmony-social-game/blob/master/contracts/contracts/Pool.sol

I too am looking for the same answer to verify if it is actually truly possible!